# Rails model - User.includes(:profile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have trouble with include statment.

My search model look like this:

```
users = User.includes(:profile)
users = users.active
users = users.where('users.age = ?', value)
users = users.where('profiles.abc = ?',value2)
```

My user model:

```
scope :active, where('users.has_photo = ?', true)
```

What's going on. When i havent got in search model 'users = users.active' - everything works. Left outer join is made. Why this "extra" statment destroy Left outer join? Im new in rails and sql soo maybe this is very simple.

When i havent got users = users.active - query is like this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "users"."id") FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles" ON "profiles"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (profiles.age >= '15') AND (profiles.age <= '75') AND (profiles.gender IN(1,2)) - this is query when everything works.
```

and with users = users.active

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: profiles.age: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"  WHERE (users.has_photo = 't') AND (profiles.age >= '21') AND (profiles.age <= '35') AND (profiles.gender IN(1,2))
```

has_photo is just a method that i call when users add photo :

```
def set_active(value)

    self.has_photo = value

  end
```

Comment: This should work. I just tested something very similar and it worked as you intended. Can you post your `User` model? Specifically, the part referencing `has_photo`?

Comment: How about showing us the queries with and without.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "users"."id") FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles" ON "profiles"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (profiles.age >= '15') AND (profiles.age <= '75') AND (profiles.gender IN(1,2)) - this is query when everything works.

Comment: and this i got when it have users = users.active - SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: profiles.age: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"  WHERE (users.has_photo = 't') AND (profiles.age >= '21') AND (profiles.age <= '35') AND (profiles.gender IN(1,2))

Comment: If this is exactly as you say it is, with no other forces at play, _it will work_. So go back and look at it because this is not the whole story.

Comment: Have you posted the entire code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why are you adding each statement in a new line and not just chain then like this:

```
users = User.includes(:profile).active.where('users.age = ? AND profiles.abc = ?', value, value2)
```

should work without any problems

EDIT:
given your comment I think you should then change scope to be a Proc

```
scope :active, Proc.new { where(:has_photo => true) }
```

I'm not sure about the reason but since Rails 4 all scopes are required to be Procs so there must be one!

EDIT: stevanity is more knowledgable on this topic

> Well the reason for requiring procs or lambdas or simple blocks {} is
>   to avoid eager evaluation of the queries. Such queries are evaluated
>   into SQL when the model is loaded for the first time. So if you had
>   specified a condition that was actually dynamic like where(:created_at
>   => Date.today), then it would always return the records created on the day the particular application was started! To avoid all this Rails4
>   requires scopes to have a callable proc/function/block/lambda as
>   argument so they can be called and evaluated whenever needed.

Comment: because i have users = users.where("profiles.age <= ?", age_to) if age_to.present?

Comment: ok, and if you chain first two and add other two in new lines, that happens? Please also update your code to reflect ACTUAL logic, it may be important

Comment: and second thing - when i do this users = users.where('users.has_photo = ?', true) instead users = users.active - it works

Comment: Two random ideas. 1. change order and do `.active` first and `includes` second. 2. Change `active` to Proc, like `scope :active, Proc.new { where(:has_photo => true) }`

Comment: 1,2 = works, but why my version doesnt? Where can be problem?

Comment: I am not sure about the details but I think it's some ruby catch In Rails 4 all scopes are required to be proc's and there is probably a good reason for that.

Comment: ok so that is rails 4 problem - i have something like this but written in rails 3.2 - so thats's why. Ok thanks for saving some hours of searching :) and i must read about scopes in rails 4.

Comment: It's not Rails 4 problem. I just missed a dot between sentences.

Comment: When you go for the scope, the first active record query gets processed and a seperate join query is generated and users and profiles are loaded. After that when you try to filter using profiles field it gives you the error because the includes part isnt in the second query. Check your log and you'll see a previous query! :)

Comment: ok scope :active, -> { where has_photo: true } this also works ... i must learn more :)

Comment: and i know that it isnt "problem" of rails 4. Its some change relative to 3.2 - i think..:)

Comment: Well the reason for requiring procs or lambdas or simple blocks {} is to avoid eager evaluation of the queries. Such queries are evaluated into SQL when the model is loaded for the first time. So if you had specified a condition that was actually dynamic like `where(:created_at => Date.today)`, then it would always return the records created on the day the particular application was started! To avoid all this Rails4 requires scopes to have a callable proc/function/block/lambda as argument so they can be called and evaluated whenever needed.